# Change fancybox title when iframe changes location

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox, title

Is there a way to dynamically change the title on a fancybox after it has loaded -- at any time using javascript?

I'm using a fancybox iframe and want to dynamically show the url of the iframe even if the user clicks around inside the iframe and goes to different locations.

Comment: so if you open google (for instance) inside the iframe then the title should say "google" but if you navigate inside the iframe to bbc, then the title should change dynamically to "bbc"?

Comment: Yes. I still can't figure out how to change the title attribute after the fancybox is drawn. I've tried $("a#ideas").attr('title',"changeit");

Comment: I've been playing around more and think it may be impossible since there would be cross domain issues. The fancybox is in the main page, the iframe is at another domain.